# How to use TCppWebBrowser on RAD 10.4

Tags: c++builder-10.4-sydney

The code below used to be perfect to C++Builder 6.0, but it is not compiling on RAD 10.4 Sydney.
I am not familiar with OLE controls and its classes and methods.
Can someone help me to make it work?

PogBrowser is a TCppWebBrowser.

```
void __fastcall TRelatPOG::ShowStream( TStream *stm )
{
    try
    {
         if( !PogBrowser->Document )
        {
             PogBrowser->Navigate(L"about:blank");
             while( PogBrowser->ReadyState != 4 )         
                Application->ProcessMessages();
        }

        IPersistStreamInit *psi;
        TStreamAdapter *sa = new   TStreamAdapter(stm,soReference);
        if( sa )
        {
            if (SUCCEEDED(PogBrowser->Document->QueryInterface(IID_IPersistStreamInit,(void **)&psi)))
            {
                psi->InitNew();
                psi->Load(*sa);// Compile error
                psi->Release();
            }
            delete sa;
        }
     }
     catch(Exception *E)
     {
         MessageDlg(String(E->ClassName()) + " ( " + E->Message + " )", mtError, TMsgDlgButtons() << mbOK, 0);
     }
 }
```

Comment: The code shown in the example at https://edn.embarcadero.com/article/26729 does not work on RAD 10.4 Sydney. It does not compile due to class conversion error.

Comment: On C++Builder 6.0 the implementation of the class TStreamAdapter differ from RAD 10.4 Sydney, it only has one inconditional operator IStream(), which apparently is called by default.

Comment: The implementation on the Sydney version of RAD is different and has two different operators which I migth have to use explicitly, I do not know how to do it though.

Comment: What is the EXACT compiler error you are getting? Also, you are leaking the `TStreamAdapter` object

Comment: [bcc32 Error] URelatPOG.cpp(194): E2034 Cannot convert 'TStreamAdapter' to 'IStream *'

Answer (score 1):

Once upon a time, `TStreamAdapter` used to implicitly convert to `IStream*`,  but now it implicitly converts to `_di_IStream` instead (ie `DelphiInterface<IStream>`).

`IPersistStreamInit::Save()` requires `IStream*`, thus requires 2 conversions (`TStreamAdapter` -> `_di_IStream` -> `IStream*`), but C++ only allows 1 *implicit* conversion at a time.

So, you need to cast the `TStreamAdapter` to `_di_IStream` *explicitly*, which can then convert to `IStream*` *implicitly*, eg:

```
psi->Load(static_cast<_di_IStream>(*sa));
```

However, a better solution would be to let `_di_IStream` handle the lifetime of the `TStreamAdapter` to begin with, eg:

```
_di_IPersistStreamInit psi;
if (SUCCEEDED(PogBrowser->Document->QueryInterface(IID_IPersistStreamInit, reinterpret_cast<void**>(&psi))))
{
    _di_IStream sa(*(new TStreamAdapter(stm, soReference)));
    psi->InitNew();
    psi->Load(sa);
}
```